# Docker: Error pulling image (latest) from imageStack, operation not supported

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, docker

When I do pull on docker I get the following error:

```
2014/09/02 12:38:06 Error pulling image (latest) from imageStack, operation not supported
```

I'm using boot2dock and my docker version is:
Docker version 1.1.2, build d84a070

I have looked on Google and searched online for solutions it seems others are having this problem but no one seems to have a solution that works.Some have suggested a local build but not addressing it exactly how. So, if anyone could suggest a solution or workaround I would appreciate it.

examples:
https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/462 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6874

Comment: That's a pretty old Docker version; try updating your boot2docker/Docker stack first (v1.7.1 as of today)

Answer (score 0):

You should do an upgrade of your installation. That will fix the problem. Be aware: The upgrade will delete all the containers and images on your boot2docker VM! Here the commands, assuming that you run boot2docker on a Mac:

```
boot2docker delete
boot2docker upgrade
boot2docker init
curl https://get.docker.com/builds/Darwin/x86_64/docker-latest > /usr/local/bin/docker
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker
```